# Resizing breaks the position of my divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I created a basic clock using only div's (no images) and when rezing the clock arrows breaks and is off position as show here:

[image]                                     [image]

Why is this happening ? Can someone fix this for me? It's a single file no external files

Comment: Please include the option to mute. I stopped testing it after 20 beeps.

Comment: I think it's depends on how resize the browser. It depends on browser and on the resolution of the monitor. No idea on solving it.

Comment: Did you fixed? I'm not seeing any broken arrows!

Comment: I think this is happening because of `float` property. I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, impressive. Im not sure this qualifies as a real answer but could lead you in the right direction...

Are you meaning when you zoom in in the browser? I once had a problem that turned out to be how different browsers render subpixels. Its not exactly your problem but I think its very similar.

This page describes the problem: http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/.

The reason I think its related, is if you zoom in further on your page, the problem goes away but then comes back. It is how the browser is rendering elements that were never designed to be viewed at anything other than 100%.

You will notice too that if you zoom out the problem is the same.

**My suggestion - Dont worry about it!**

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, WOW, it's really awesome!

I see that it happens both on firefox and chrome.
When I changed the top/bottom/left/right for the triangles to 28-29px it was better positioned.

I think it has to do with the sizing method (or browser resizing bug - though I don't think so as it happens on both browsers), did you try converting the 'px' to 'em', as 'em' is meant to keep size proportions better.